# Collecting data for Body measurements with Quickpose.ai in iOS

Tags: ios, swiftui, mediapipe

I am exploring the possibility with QuickPose.ai   I have follow the exemple about the range of motion to and can print angle values in continue.

I would like to do the same with different body measurements but I dont get any return value.
The folowing section of code work when  feature1(rangeOfMotion) but not with but not feature2 (measurement)

````
    .onAppear {
                
            let bikeStyle = QuickPose.Style(relativeFontSize: 0.33, relativeArcSize: 0.4, relativeLineWidth: 0.3)
            
            let feature1: QuickPose.Feature = .rangeOfMotion(.shoulder(side: .right, clockwiseDirection: false), style: bikeStyle)
              let feature2: QuickPose.Feature = .measureLineBody(p1: .elbow(side: .left), p2: .wrist(side: .left), userHeight: 168, format: "%.1fcm",style: bikeStyle)

                
                quickPose.start(features: [.overlay(.upperBody)], onFrame: { status, image, features,  feedback, landmarks in
                    if case .success(_) = status {
                        overlayImage = image
                        
                        
                     //   quickPose.update(features: [feature1])
                     //   let result = features[feature1]
                    
                        quickPose.update(features: [feature2])
                        let result = features[feature2]
                        
                        print ("QPBV111 result: ", result as Any)
                        
                        lastResult = result?.value
                        print ("QPBV113 lastresult: ", lastResult ?? "nodata")
                        
                    }

                }
            )}  ```
````

Comment: You are asking a question about QuickPose, and you have the mediapipe tag?  What does that mean?

Comment: In case you want to know, the word 'data' is a plural form of datum.

Comment: Quickpose is based on MediaPipe and I cannot tag QuickPose in StackOverflow.  Sorry for the confusion